# How to parse xml tag using DOM parser in java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am going to parse following xml file in java using DOM parser but not getting the information to retrieve some tag from my xml file so please help me out for this.

```
<policy name="DayCapturePolicy" type="capture">
<starttime>9:00:00 AM</starttime>
<endtime>9:00:00 PM</endtime>
<event name="NEW_APP_INSTALLED">
 <eventFilter selectedAppName="Alarm"/> 
   <eventParam>selectedAppName</eventParam>
  <eventParam>selectedAppVersion</eventParam>
  <eventParam>appPackageName</eventParam>
  <eventParam>appDirPath</eventParam>
</event>
</policy>
```

I want to know how should i parse the value for event filter tag from above xml file?I also want to know how should i retrieve all the values from eventParam tag.I am able to retrieve value for first tag i.e.selectedAppName but unable to parse the value for salectedAppVersion.appPackageName,appDirPath.Thanks In advance

I had tried this code for parsing.

```
      NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("policy");
    Log.d("Reminder", "Number of Policies : "+nodeList.getLength());
    for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++){
        Log.d("Reminder", "In 1");
        //PolicyInfo policyInfo = new PolicyInfo();
        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap = node.getAttributes();
        String policyName = namedNodeMap.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
        String policyType = namedNodeMap.getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue();
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

              Element eElement = (Element) node;
              Log.d("startTime  : " ,""+ getTagValue("starttime", eElement));
              Log.d("endtime  : " ,""+ getTagValue("endtime", eElement));
              NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("event");
              for(int j=0;i<nList.getLength();i++){
                    Log.d("Reminder", "In 1");
                    //PolicyInfo policyInfo = new PolicyInfo();
                    Node innerNode = nList.item(i);
                    NamedNodeMap innerNamedNodeMap = innerNode.getAttributes();
                    String eventName = innerNamedNodeMap.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
                    Log.d("innerNode", eventName);
                    if(innerNode.getNodeType()== Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                         Element innerElement = (Element) innerNode;
                         Log.d("eventParam  : " ,""+ getTagValue("eventParam", innerElement));
                         Log.d("eventFilter  : " ,""+ getTagValue("eventFilter", innerElement));
                         //Log.d("endtime  : " ,""+ getTagValue("endtime", eElement));
                    }
              //System.out.println("starttime : " + getTagValue("starttime", eElement));
             // System.out.println("endtime: " + getTagValue("endtime", eElement));
              //System.out.println("Nick Name : " + getTagValue("nickname", eElement));
              //System.out.println("Salary : " + getTagValue("salary", eElement));

           }
        }


private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
```

Comment: can you include the code for **getTagValue**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you work with XPath expressions instead, much easier. Since you already have the `Document` just create an XPath:

```
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/policy/event/eventFilter/@selectedAppName");

NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc , XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nl.item(i);
    System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
}
```

That will print

```
Alarm
```

To get all the `<eventParam>` switch the xpath expression to `/policy/event/eventParam`.

That will print

```
selectedAppName
selectedAppVersion
appPackageName
appDirPath
```

---

Link to oracle xpath javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your code is working if there is single element of name "event" .if i add multiple element in it then it fails

Comment: @user1700156 Can you elaborate on that? I have added some more events and tested without problems.